# Infinite Qt animation (without specified duration time)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a Block Breaker clone using c++ and Qt and I would like to know how to create infinite(or unbounded) animation for the movement of the ball.

Should i stick to the animation framework (by sub-classing QAbstractAnimation), or consider creating and managing new threads for handling animations?

Some experienced guidance would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your project/post your code?

Comment: Actually I am prototyping by trying the QPropertyAnimation class no big deal...

Comment: Would you consider displaying a .gif image as an option?

Comment: No, what i want to do is animating a graphic component which is going to interact with other graphic components (collision for instance)

Comment: Can't help you there then, maybe you'd like to checkout the [Tetrix game](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/Tetrixgame.htm) in Qt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So finally I figure it out: using the `QPropertyAnimation::setLoopCount(-1)` member function makes the animation run forever until stopped with the `QPropertyAnimation::stop()` signal...